# Can I use an environment other than 'test' for Ember tests?

Tags: ember.js

I have Ember.js 2.16 acceptance tests written using the Ember template test libraries (QUnit and testem) that test the general functionality of an Ember app. When I run `ember test`, the 'environment' for which environment variables are retrieved is always set to `test`.

Is there a way to run `ember test` with any environment other than `test`? Running it with `--environment="my_other_test_env"` doesn't change the environment as it would for `ember build` or `ember serve`.

I’d like to be able to pass parameters to acceptance tests depending on what environment they are running in. Is this behavior supported, and if not, is there a reason I shouldn't be doing this? I understand that for lower-level unit testing, I shouldn't be dealing with external dependencies, but for end-to-end acceptance testing, it seems normal that there would be different environments I would want to run the tests in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use your own environment variable:

Run with `TEST_ENV=...`

```
$ TEST_ENV=special ember test
```

Add it to your app configuration:

```
// config/environment.js
if (environment === 'test') {
    ENV.testingEnvironment = process.env.TEST_ENV;
    ...
}
```

And use it in your acceptance test like:

```
import ENV from '../../config/environment';

alert(ENV.testingEnvironment); // outputs 'special'
```

I'm using similar way to deploy a production build to a staging environment, but only changing some api endpoints in the configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. I was hoping to use the environments by name as I would for a normal ember build/serve, but after a deep dive into the docs and fiddling with it myself, I'm pretty sure that just isn't possible. This seems like a great alternative that's just as simple.